# Why update weights and biases of network two times using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Here I have implementation of DenseLayer and DenseNetwork using tensorflow. I can't understand here why we update weight and biases two times. One in backward method from DenseLayer and second time in train method of DenseNetwork. Can you please explain that part? First I thought there might be typo so I removed second updates and loss didn't decrease. So there must be reason for doing two updates.

```
class DenseLayer(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(DenseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.output_size = output_size

        self.weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([input_size, output_size], stddev=0.01))
        self.biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([output_size]))

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.forward(inputs)

    def forward(self, inputs):
        self.last_input = inputs
        self.z = tf.matmul(inputs, self.weights) + self.biases
        return self.z

    def backward(self, d_L_d_out, learning_rate):
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
            d_L_d_inputs = tf.matmul(d_L_d_out, tf.transpose(self.weights))

        d_L_d_weights = tape.gradient(d_L_d_inputs, self.weights)
        d_L_d_biases = tape.gradient(d_L_d_inputs, self.biases)

        self.weights.assign_sub(learning_rate * d_L_d_weights)
        self.biases.assign_sub(learning_rate * d_L_d_biases)

        return d_L_d_inputs

class DenseNetwork(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(DenseNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.layers = []

    def add_layer(self, layer):
        self.layers.append(layer)

    def __call__(self, inputs):
        return self.forward(inputs)


    def forward(self, inputs):
        for layer in self.layers:
            inputs = layer.forward(inputs)
        return inputs

    def backward(self, d_L_d_out, learning_rate):
        for layer in reversed(self.layers):
            d_L_d_out = layer.backward(d_L_d_out, learning_rate)

    def train(self, inputs, targets, learning_rate, epochs):
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            loss = 0
            with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape:
                output = self.forward(inputs)
                loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - targets))

            grads = tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)
            for i, layer in enumerate(self.layers):
              layer.biases.assign(layer.biases - learning_rate*grads[2*i])
              layer.weights.assign(layer.weights - learning_rate * grads[2*i+1])

            if (epoch + 1) % 10 == 0:
                tf.print(f"Epoch {epoch+1} - Loss: {loss}")

    def loss(self, output, target):
        return tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - target))
```

Comment: When you say "I removed second updates and loss didn't decrease", do you mean it didn't decrease during training? Do you call the train method during training?  I don't see anything here call the `backward` method.  Is that called elsewhere in your code?  If not, try deleting ***that*** and see if the loss still decreases.

Comment: @Joe Deleted backward method and still works fine, training loss decreases.

Comment: So maybe it's there to show it can be done in two ways? Because what's the point if it doesn't do anything

Comment: You would have to ask whoever wrote the code, but I suspect that the `backward` method was not working correctly, so he/she implemented the gradient update in the `train` method, using a different technique, i.e. `tape.gradient(loss, self.trainable_variables)`